# How many bags of concrete do I need?

Tags: concrete, slab

I would like to make a small concrete slab of the following dimensions.

```
Length: 1.2m
Width: 0.86m
Depth: 0.09m
```

The cubic volume as i understand it is all those numbers multiplied.
result: 0.0929m<sup>2</sup>

If a bag of pre-mix concrete says
0.2m<sup>2</sup> x 50mm

How many bags would I need?

Update: Brick BBQ construction. I am doing this for "homework" :) 
[image]

Comment: Your volume should be in cubic meters. Trivial, but true.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would say 10 or 11 bags (depending on how sloppy you are).

```
0.2 * .05 = .01

.0929 / .01 = 9.29 bags
```

Since you never get perfect yield from a bag, I would personally go with 11 bags.

Comment: It might be that it actually says a square .2 meters on a side. This seems a more likely way of specifying the useful volume of the bag. Just in case that makes your numbers off by 1/2. The number in that case would be 19 or 20 bags.

Comment: Looking again, this looks like a homework problem, so it doesn't have to reflect common sense at all.

Comment: "Homework"? I guess it is. See my in progress home work LOL. Have updated my post. The calculation was quite accurate. After resizing the slab, we calculated 12 bags. I bought 14 and returned 1 back to the shop.

Comment: Nice work, Valamas.

Comment: Glad it worked out for you! Very nice fire place too!